# Do I use a JoinableTaskFactory with AspNetCore?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await

I've imported [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading/) into .Net Core Web App. I did this specifically to make use of [`AsyncLazy<T>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading/blob/master/src/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading/AsyncLazy.cs).

I wanted to make sure I did this right, so I imported the appropriate [Analyzers](https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading/blob/master/doc/analyzers/index.md).

The warnings and the documentation clearly state that a [`JoinableTaskFactory`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading/blob/master/doc/library_with_jtf.md) should be injected into my implementation.

My question is, how should I instantiate that `JoinableTaskFactory` in the configuration of my .Net Core Web App?

Is it as simple as

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
        services.AddSingleton(new JoinableTaskFactory());
    // ...
}
```

or, is that all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page of the vs-threading docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading/blob/master/doc/testing_vs.md) says

> The ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory property only works for code running in the VS process. If your code is running out of proc (in the vstest.executionengine.exe runner for instance) it won't work.

So, as the name of the package, `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading`, suggests, it's intended to be used for Visual Studio extensions. The code that you linked for its implementation of AsyncLazy uses JoinableTaskFactory, so it's probably not suitable outside of Visual Studio. I certainly would never use it outside of a VS extension that needs to switch to the UI thread.

[Steven Cleary's AsyncEx library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx) has an [AsyncLazy](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/AsyncLazy.cs), and [the wiki page](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLazy) links to this [Steven Toub blog post titled AsyncLazy](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/asynclazyt/). The blog post points out that the lazy semantics doesn't really add much over what `Task<T>` provides, although since the value factory might do a lot of work before reaching an await his sample runs it on the thread pool and unwraps the `Task<Task<T>>`.

edit: As pointed out in the comments, my quote from the docs is somewhat out of context. However, the vs-threading library is about avoiding deadlocks when using async with a synchronisation context (primarily a GUI). ASP.NET Core, what the author of the question is using, does not have a synchronisation context, hence doesn't need to worry about deadlocking the main thread specifically. While using the vs-threading library probably won't cause problems, as my quote claimed, I still don't think it's a good fit for anything without a synchronisation context and there are much better alternatives, like using `Task<T>` directly and not need any AsyncLazy implementation.

Comment: So, I'm going to do what I should've done in the first place and use [Nito.AsyncEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx) instead.

Comment: I'd disagree with this statement. While the quoted documentation is about testing **VS Extesions** specifically, the front page/readme says its an xplat library and and we know Visual Studio is just running on windows (Visual Studio for mac is just rebranded Xamarin Studio). https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading/blob/master/doc/library_with_jtf.md is more clear on the instructions specifically "Singleton class with JoinableTaskContext property" section and "Accept JoinableTaskContext as a constructor argument".

Comment: The important thing is that `new`ing `JoinableTaskContext` happens on the main thread (the one you want your stuff being joined on), be it the thread of the main method, UI thread or some other context (i.e. aspnet core or orleans schedule context)

Comment: @Tseng you're right, I was too quick to copy paste. I edited my answer to try to clarify my position that using a library designed for avoiding deadlocks when using async with a synchronisation context isn't the best choice when using a framework that doesn't use synchronisation contexts.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The doc it references is referring specifically to `ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory`. The `ThreadHelper` class is defined in the VS SDK so of course it's only available for VS extensions. But `JoinableTaskFactory` itself can and does frequently get used outside of VS.
The name "VisualStudio" appears in the package and assembly name because the VS team created and maintains it. It has no bearing on which kinds of apps can use it.

Comment: One of the reasons to use `AsyncLazy<T>` instead of `Task<T>` in ASP.Net Core is disposing logic of the standard DI container - if one registers `Task<T>`, the container sooner or later tries to dispose it, which can cause exceptions.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading` library in ASP.NET Core applications. But while `JoinableTaskFactory` would "work" in such an app, it's a pretty good sign you're doing something wrong.

The analyzers are always appropriate of course, and the warnings you saw were perhaps pointing out that you shouldn't call `Task.Result`, `Task.Wait()`, etc. These synchronously block threads and can *severely* reduce the scalability of your web app (or any app for that matter). You should use *await* instead wherever possible.

`JoinableTaskFactory` is there to step in when you *can't* use *await* but you still need to call async code. Using `JTF.Run` will still block the calling thread, but it will do so in a way that avoids deadlocks when you have a single threaded `SynchronizationContext` in the application. I don't *think* ASP.NET Core has such a thing, so that's not a concern. `JTF.Run` is still more efficient than `Task.Wait` since it can reuse the original thread for continuations instead of a second thread.

If you *do* choose to use JTF in your web app, if ASP.NET Core doesn't use a single-threaded `SynchronizationContext` then you can create and share a single JTF instance with the entire app. But if it *does* have a single-threaded `SynchronizationContext`, it will be one per web request, which means you need to create a new `JoinableTaskContext` for *each* request since these are affinitized to one `SynchronizationContext`. You always get your JTF instance from a `JoinableTaskContext` instance.

Comment: for the record, I now think what I was doing was all wrong. Which I think is what you are saying, in a more constructive way.

Comment: Yes. Feel free to change the accepted answer to this one. :)

Comment: How about you provide a working example.  That would be useful.  There are parameters to the constructor that I've never seen before.  How deep does this rabbit hole get?

Comment: @Quarkly: `new JoinableTaskContext()` ought to work. :)

Comment: @AndrewArnott so basically I can use `new JoinableTaskFactory(new JoinableTaskContext())` in multiple places for a request and the context will be fine?

Comment: We recently had to fix an ASP.NET (Core?) where `JoinableTaskContext` was created a _lot_, and it led to very large arrays in .NET's CallContext of wasted objects. You should create just _one_ `JoinableTaskContext` per request at most, and one for the process may be much better. So long as you create it while `SynchronizationContext.Current == null` you can reuse it everywhere. And since it has a `Factory` property on it, you don't even have to create `JoinableTaskFactory` by hand.

Comment: @AndrewArnott where is this factory property for .NET 6 / .NET Core? `ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory` is only available for .NET Framework.

Comment: @PeetBrits `ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory` is in fact only available within Visual Studio, as `ThreadHelper` is part of the VS SDK. For your own application, you can and should create one `JoinableTaskContext` object of your own and use that one object throughout your application. You can share it through a common property the way VS does through its own `ThreadHelper` class.

Comment: In my ASP.NET Core app I wanted to use `new AsyncReaderWriterLock()`, but an analyzer included with the assembly that contains `AsyncReaderWriterLock` says "VSTHRD012: Provide an instance of JoinableTaskFactory to avoid deadlocks with the main thread". Well, I'm not sure if ASP.NET apps *have* a main thread, but none of the constructor overloads accept a `JoinableTaskFactory` anyway! ‍♂️