# Optimising an asynchronous call in a constructor using JoinableTaskFactory.Run

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, async-await, fluentvalidation, .net-6.0

In a constructor that gets dependency injected I need to make an asynchronous call.

(This was not originally my code. It gets used in many places. I don't think it's relevant, but this is part of an implementation for `FluentValidation.AbstractValidator<T>`. The implementation of `ConfigureValidationRulesAsync()` is in the base class.)

```
public class SampleClass<TModel> : SampleBase<TModel>, ISampleClass
{
    public SampleClass()
    {
        // ... RuleFor(...);

        var genericInstance = Activator.CreateInstance<TModel>();
        Task.Run(() => ConfigureValidationRulesAsync(this, genericInstance)).Wait();
    }
}
```

This gave me the following warning.

> VSTHRD002
>
> Synchronously waiting on tasks or awaiters may cause deadlocks. Use await or JoinableTaskFactory.Run instead.

Which I followed...

```
public class SampleClass<TModel> : SampleBase<TModel>, ISampleClass
{
    public SampleClass()
    {
        // ... RuleFor(...);

        // Using "JoinableTaskFactory()" directly because "ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory" is .NET Framework, not .NET 6.

        var genericInstance = Activator.CreateInstance<TModel>();
        var joinable = new JoinableTaskFactory(new JoinableTaskContext());
        joinable.Run(async () => await ConfigureValidationRulesAsync(this, genericInstance));
    }
}
```

But now I'm getting a new suggestion (not a warning, at least).

> VSTHRD104
>
> Expose an async version of this method that does not synchronously block. Then simplify this method to call that async method within a JoinableTaskFactory.Run delegate.

According to [this documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/blob/main/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD104.md), here is my first (bad) attempt, which failed to make the suggestion go away.

```
public class SampleClass<TModel> : SampleBase<TModel>, ISampleClass
{
    public SampleClass()
    {
        var joinable = new JoinableTaskFactory(new JoinableTaskContext());
        joinable.Run(async () => await SampleClassAsync());
    }

    public async Task SampleClassAsync()
    {
        // ... RuleFor(...);

        var genericInstance = Activator.CreateInstance<TModel>();
        await ConfigureValidationRulesAsync(this, genericInstance);
    }
}
```

My second attempt resolved the suggestion, but triggered a different suggestion.

```
public class SampleClass<TModel> : SampleBase<TModel>, ISampleClass
{
    public SampleClass()
    {
        ConfigureRules();
    }

    private void ConfigureRules()
    {
        var joinable = new JoinableTaskFactory(new JoinableTaskContext());
        joinable.Run(async () => await ConfigureRulesAsync());
    }

    private async Task ConfigureRulesAsync()
    {
        // ... RuleFor(...);

        var genericInstance = Activator.CreateInstance<TModel>();
        await ConfigureValidationRulesAsync(this, genericInstance);
    }
}
```

> VSTHRD102
>
> Limit use of synchronously blocking method calls such as JoinableTaskFactory.Run or Task.Result to public entrypoint members where you must be synchronous. Using it for internal members can needlessly add synchronous frames between asynchronous frames, leading to threadpool exhaustion.

Is this possible to resolve these suggestions for a dependency injected constructor? Or should I rather just ignore the `JoinableTaskFactory.Run` suggestiongs and keep my code in the constructor?

Comment: I think what it wants you to do is this ```joinable.Run(() => SampleClassAsync());```. But Im not entierly sure. Try it.

Comment: @Max. Nope, it gives the same warning. But I did not realise you could use it like this.

Comment: So you are getting to all this trouble just to satisfy the [analyzers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/disable-code-analysis?view=vs-2022) of the [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading/) package? AFAIK the `JoinableTaskFactory` is an obscure class, intended (I guess) for writing extensions for the Visual Studio. It's not for every day use.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias It's hard to get proper information about it, but according to the comments in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55558845/371917), `ThreadHelper` is for VS extensions, but `JoinableTaskFactory` can get used outside VS. Also, it is a [recommended pattern](https://github.com/microsoft/vs-threading/issues/447#issuecomment-481481389).

Comment: @Peet my objection is that if the [`JoinableTaskFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.joinabletaskfactory) is a pattern recommended by Microsoft for general usage, then they haven't done a good job at promoting this pattern, by publishing well written articles and blog posts about it. Personally I consider myself quite well informed about the asynchronous technologies, and I have no idea what is the problem that this class in intended to solve. Show me the problem, then show me the solution, and then I might buy it.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I hear you. I only discovered this yesterday, as we only recently upgraded to .NET 6. When I saw a warning saying "may cause deadlocks" I figured that this is probably something important, so here I am.

Comment: @Peet I've upvoted the question, and I hope that someone will be able to come up with an answer, so that we all become wiser. But I am not holding my breath! :-)

Comment: Prevent using incoming dependencies and especially doing anything that causes I/O (and async operations) in your injection constructors. [Injection constructors should be simple](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). In the context of Fluent Validation, its [MustAsync](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/async.html) method might be of help to you, as it allows you to postpone the validation until after construction and prevents the operation to be blocked.

Comment: Yeah you can do factories or some random initialize function. Dependency Injection gets quite difficult with those. Would be great if we could just declare an async constructor. I think the problem JoinableTaskFactory tries to solve does not exist on .net 6 (since .net core). If the code is in a .net standard 2.0 library the suggestion is 'relevant' as it could be used in .net 4.8. otherwise it's pretty meaningless. While I'm sure you can create a deadlock somehow in .net 6 with .Wait/.Result etc. I've never seen it. You certainly have to try a lot harder and this likely won't solve it.

Comment: In .net 4.8 and below it was quite common to deadlock with blocking tasks. Has to do with there only being one synchronization context. Since .net core there is no such thing. So you don't have to worry about blocking the main thread at least. Solutions to solve that specifically won't get you anywhere even if you manage to deadlock in .net 6 (if you do I'm curious how you managed to do so).

Comment: @Steven I completely agree with the constructor comment. I had a look at the code, and it's rather involved. The reason for the async is that there is one very specialised situation in only one of the many possible cases, and this one special case needs to check something in the DB before setting up the rule. So, for pretty much every case the async will just return immediately.

Comment: @Max thanks, that's very interesting. So, the practical question, do I lose anything if I use `JoinableTaskFactory` instead of `Task.Run(...).Wait()`? (Or vice versa?) E.g. just to make the warning go away? (And obviously then be very strict about never adding new code that adds async to a constructor.)

Comment: As others said before vs-threading seems to be ment for developing visual studio plugins. If you don't you probably should not use it. As far I can tell the warning is probably generated by the package itself. When you remove the nuget package the warning should also go away. If it still sticks around it might be part of the visual studio plugin dev tools you can install optionally when installing visual studio. I never checked this box don't know if it does that. This is not a warning you should be getting in the first place.

Comment: I think you guys are right. The [documentation for `JoinableTaskFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.joinabletaskfactory?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) talks about mitigating deadlocks when tasks require the main thread of an application, when the main thread may itself be blocking on the completion of a task, which does not apply to ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @Max the warning came from the NuGet package `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.Analyzers`. I'm keeping it installed because it will be useful in other cases where people use things like `MethodAsync().Result` or `MethodAsync().Wait()` when it should be `await MethodAsync()` (yes, we had a couple of those, and it caused weird runtime issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the best set of conclusions that I could derive from all the comments on the question.

### Point #1: Injection Constructors should be simple

[Injection constructors should be simple](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/), and in the context of Fluent Validation, the [MustAsync](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/async.html) method should help to simplify asynchronous validation.

### Point #2: Warning not applicable to .NET Core

While I can use `JoinableTaskFactory`, I should not be getting this warning, because the problem it is trying to solve is not applicable to .NET Core.

Below is the description from the [documentation for `JoinableTaskFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.joinabletaskfactory?view=visualstudiosdk-2022). It applies to situations where joining threads to the main thread could cause deadlocks.

> A factory for starting asynchronous tasks that can mitigate deadlocks when the tasks require the Main thread of an application and the Main thread may itself be blocking on the completion of a task.

Thus, one can safely ignore the warning in the cases where it is simply not possible to rewrite the code. (Note the use of `Task.Run()`, which is [the recommended way to launch a compute-bound task as of .NET Framework 4.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew?view=net-6.0#remarks).)

```
#pragma warning disable VSTHRD002 // Avoid problematic synchronous waits
        Task.Run(() => MethodAsync()).Wait();
#pragma warning restore VSTHRD002 // Avoid problematic synchronous waits
```

### Point #3: How to implement `JoinableTaskFactory`

If you want to use `JoinableTaskFactory` anyway, this is taken from comments on [another related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60746471/371917).

For .NET Framework projects, use `ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory`.

For .NET Core projects, if you want to use `JoinableTaskFactory`, do not create a new context every time you use it. You should create one shared `JoinableTaskContext` object and use that one object throughout the application (per request or per process). This is the case when `SynchronizationContext.Current == null`.

### Point #4: Visual Studio Warnings

The warning comes from the NuGet package `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.Analyzers`. It is useful to keep it installed, because it will also warn you when you use code like `MethodAsync().Result` or `MethodAsync().Wait()` when you should instead be using `await MethodAsync()`.