Avoid awaiting foreign Tasks in ASP.NET Core
I have analyzed my project using Microsoft.Visual Studio.Threading.Analyzers.
I get the following warning on the await task: 
Link: https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-threading/blob/main/doc/analyzers/VSTHRD003.md
I don't quite understand, does this have something to do with the synchronization context? I use ASP.NET Core, but as far as I understand it is not there.
public async Task WaitTestAsync(Task<string> task)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000000);
    await task;
}

How do I make this code valid? I tried to write this through JoinableTaskFactory, but the warning doesn't work.
string result;

JoinableTask joinableTask = joinableTaskFactory.RunAsync(async () =>
{
    result = await task;
});

A similar warning occurs in my middleware on the await t:
public class GrpcExceptionInterceptor : Interceptor
{
    private readonly ILogger<GrpcExceptionInterceptor> _logger;

    public GrpcExceptionInterceptor(ILogger<GrpcExceptionInterceptor> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override AsyncUnaryCall<TResponse> AsyncUnaryCall<TRequest, TResponse>(
        TRequest request,
        ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context,
        AsyncUnaryCallContinuation<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
    {
        var call = continuation(request, context);

        return new AsyncUnaryCall<TResponse>(HandleResponse(call.ResponseAsync), call.ResponseHeadersAsync, call.GetStatus, call.GetTrailers, call.Dispose);
    }

    private async Task<TResponse> HandleResponse<TResponse>(Task<TResponse> t)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await t;
            return response;
        }
        catch (RpcException e)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Error calling via grpc: {Status} - {Message}", e.Status, e.Message);
            return default;
        }
    }
}


Can you explain what was your intention with that code?

@PauloMorgado In the first case, this is a PubSub implementation. If there is no value, I make a subscription.

Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

@PauloMorgado I found that any method where the Task is passed is suitable for an example. Changed the question.

@WebFR post your code, not any method. HandleResponse is unusual. PubSub libraries don't need such code. A Task represents something that's already running and may be itself awaiting for your code to complete. If you only intend to read the result, why not pass just TResponse and let whatever calls HandleResponse do the waiting?

You'll find methods that accept a Func<...,Task> which allows the handler to actually execute the request asynchronously and handle the response, perhaps even retry with delays, or use Polly. The question's HandleResponse<TResponse> only hides exception before returning null. It has no access to parameters or other info, so it can't add useful information to the log message. You could log the request that caused the error, or at least some ID

@PanagiotisKanavos I have added the entire middleware code. I would like to understand why the Microsoft.Visual Studio.Threading.Analyzer package issues a warning in the simplest first section of the code (await task in method  WaitTestAsync).

I explained why. This code can easily deadlock itself if that task awaits something signaled by your handler, eg a TaskCompletionSource. The way the AsyncUnaryCall method returns a still running operation isn't great either. Should something happen you'll have a very hard time understanding what actually threw

@PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the help. Judging by the information from the other answer, these recommendations are relevant for the development of Visual Studio extensions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76005919/how-to-solve-avoid-foreign-task-warning-using-joinabletaskfactory.
The JoinableTaskFactory itself comes from the Microsoft.Visual Studio.Threading package, so it probably has nothing to do with ASP.NET Core.

@PanagiotisKanavos There is a more detailed answer on this topic, which is in ASP.NET Core is missing the SynchronizationContext and this is not a problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55535494/do-i-use-a-joinabletaskfactory-with-aspnetcore
